# Skip component while patching

Tags: windows-installer

I have an installer with a component, which stores an absolute path in registry. Name of the folder will be set via command line.

Everything work fine on installation. But, by patching property that points to the folder will be not resolved (i suppose, because this folder contains only subfolders and there is no files installed).

Result: Property becomes value from TARGETDIR and overwrites it into registry.

Is there any possibility to skip installation of a single component by patch/reinstall?

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be your assumption that the install will preserve the values of a property you set on the command line, but it won't. However if the folder is preserved somewhere in the registry then the usual way to restore it is for you to add an AppSearch to your patch that will read that registry item and populate the TARGETDIR property to the correct value.

Comment: Well, there would be no probles, if at least one file would be installed in that folder :) Because, i'd set this file as KeyPath for the component and the full path would be stored in registry.

Solution with AppSearch is already impemented. But i don't like it :) Because of two reasons:
1) it does not work properly. AppSearch does not run while uninstallation. So if i uninstall that patch the Registry Value is reseted to TARGETDIR
2) this solution is too massive (we generate wxs files)

Comment: AppSearch does run during uninstall unless it's been conditioned out.